# Jasmine strange reference behavior based on commenting out functions

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, jasmine

I am doing some unit testing with Jasmine and I am having this strange reference behavior. I am using ASP.NET core with Chutzpah to view my client testing. Here is my test file:

```js
/// <reference path="..\..\Project.Web\wwwroot\lib\jquery\dist\jquery.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../Project.Web/wwwroot/js/alerts.js"/>

describe("clearAlerts", function () {

    beforeEach(function () {

        this.mockContainer = {
            children: function () {
                return this.mockChildrenObj
            },
            mockChildrenObj: {
                addClass: function (text) { this.filledData = [text] },
                filledData: ["NO_DATA"]
            }
        }
    });

    it("should add the class is-hidden to the container", function () {

        // Act
        clearAlerts(this.mockContainer);

        // Assert
        expect(this.mockContainer.mockChildrenObj.filledData).toEqual(["is-hidden"]);
    });
});
```

And my src:

```js
function clearAlerts($alertsContainer) {
    $alertsContainer.children().addClass("is-hidden");
}

function sendErrorAlert(message, $notificationElem, $inputElemToHighlight = null) {

    // Shows the notification
    $notificationElem.removeClass("is-hidden");
    $notificationElem.children('#errorNotificationMsg').first().text(message);

    // Test to see if we need to highlight an input element
    if ($inputElemToHighlight != null) {
        $inputElemToHighlight.addClass("is-danger");
    }

    var height = $notificationElem.innerHeight();
    var left = $(document).innerWidth() / 2 - $notificationElem.innerWidth() / 2;
    $notificationElem.css({ top: (-1 * height), left: left }).animate({ top: `+=${height}px` }, "slow", "swing");
}
```

Just running the test just like this, I have the following error in my test explorer:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: clearAlerts in (PATH HERE)/Project/Project.test/client/alerts.test.js (line 21)
```

HOWEVER, if I comment out the entirety of *sendErrorAlert*, the test passes! I have no configuration folders, as visual studio seems to be able to handle the packages. I just can't get my test to reference the function when there are other functions. This has been the case for other files as well. Any help will be greatly appreciated for a stack overflow newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue! Having the default value for *$inputElemToHighlight* in the function parameter caused the file to not compile.